# Given billions of URLs, how to determine duplicate content

Tags: web-services, web

I was asked this question in a programming interview. I have described the question in detail below. It was an open-ended question.

Given billions of URLs(deep links), how do I classify that which URLs point to the duplicate content. The question was further extended to finding out that in cases of duplicate pages, which of them was authentic. This was the first part.
My approach (with valid assumptions) was to classify them on the basis of domains and then match the contents of URLs in the same bucket.

In the second part, the interviewer narrowed down the question stating that:
Given just two URLs, URL1 is a wiki page about a celebrity, (eg: Brad Pitt) and URL2 contains information about many celebrities including Brad Pitt.
How do we identify which one is authentic and which is duplicate ?
My answer was based on comparing the two pages on the basis of their citations.

The interviewer asked me to build the answer from scratch, and wanted me to assume that we don't have any prior information about duplicate content on the URLs.
Since its an open-ended question, any lead would prove helpful.

Comment: You could also check the domain that contains too much duplicated content, and check the headers served with the content ( time of modification if available ) guessing that the most recent content is the duplicate one.

Comment: Updated the question.
@dvhh: The interviewer asked me to build the answer from scratch, and wanted me to assume that we don't have any prior information about duplicate content on the URLs.

Comment: I would say the question belong more to http://programmers.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

You might find this paper to be helpful: "[Finding Near-Duplicate Web Pages: A Large-Scale Evaluation of Algorithms](http://www-scf.usc.edu/~csci572/papers/Henzinger.pdf)" by Monika Henzinger at Google, as this problem has attracted a fair amount of research. From the paper:

> A naive solution is to compare all pairs to documents. Since this is
>   prohibitively expensive on large datasets, Manber [11] and Heintze [9]
>   proposed first algorithms for detecting near-duplicate documents with
>   a reduced number of comparisons. Both algorithms work on sequences of
>   adjacent characters. Brin et al. [1](http://www-scf.usc.edu/~csci572/papers/Henzinger.pdf) started to use word sequences to
>   detect copyright violations. Shivakumar and Garcia-Molina [13, 14]
>   continued this research and focused on scaling it up to multi-gigabyte
>   databases [15]. Broder et al. [3] also used word sequences to
>   efficiently find near duplicate web pages. Later, Charikar [4]
>   developed an approach based on random projections of the words in a
>   document. Recently Hoad and Zobel [10] developed and compared methods
>   for identifying versioned and plagiarised documents.

In other words, it's a complex problem with a variety of solutions of varying success, and not something with a 'right' answer. Most of the answers involve checking word or character sequences.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: @Andrea - Is that better?

Answer (score 0):

The above link for me did not work, but I found [this page](https://nlp.stanford.edu/IR-book/html/htmledition/near-duplicates-and-shingling-1.html) from Stanford, which had an interesting theorem involving shingles and the Jaccard coefficient.